# Sorting vertex in vector with std::pair

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

I tried to return elements in vector where second element in pair is first element in second pair. For example:

input: (4,2), (4,5), (5,2)
output: (4,5), (5,2)

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> buff;

for (auto elem : buff){
    auto searching = elem.second;

    for (auto el : buff){
        if ( el.first == searching ){
            vec.push_back(el);
            vec.push_back(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for other examples.

Comment: Are you looking for cases where `vec[n].second == vec[n + 1].first`?

Comment: Yes, it works but only if vec is in sequence.

Comment: What are some examples that "don't work"? What does it do? What *should* it do in those cases?

Comment: For example: input: (4,2), (4,5), (5,2) output: (4,5), (5,2) it work,
but for (5,2) ,(4,2), (4,5) I get empty vec, although the outputs should be the same.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e5b10d426db5c29)

Comment: So the question becomes how to sort a vector?

Comment: "Yes, it works but only if vec is in sequence." I'm not sure what this statement means. All `std::vector`s are [sequence containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Sequence_containers), so I assume you don't mean that. Are you asking how to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?